# Pass Image ID to Modal with AJAX / JSON Data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

**Update:**

The duplicate answer link posted deals with binding click events to dynamically generated content - which helped, thanks. But I'm still unsure of how to pass the `$row` ID of dynamically generated content to a dynamically generated modal using a click event within an AJAX statement?

So essentially, where/how does the `$row` id go in:

```
<a href="#dataModal"><img class="photog-headshot" 
src="images/'+ data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="' + 
data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '"></a>
```

**Problem:**

I'm working with code from the tutorial below and incorporating it into my existing project and I'm stuck. I'm not triggering the `.view_data` from the `href` on line 18 in `surfboard.js` so when a surfboard placeholder image is clicked at the bottom of of the page on [Nalu.live/equipment](http://nalu.live/equipment.php#dataModal) nothing from the database appears in the modal. The functionality I want is working in the 'Surfboard Name' table above the image grid. Click on the "View" button to see it in action.

I'm also getting a weird Unrecognized expression console log error?

**Helpful links:**

- [Tutorial: PHP Ajax Display Dynamic MySQL Data in Bootstrap Modal](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/09/php-ajax-display-dynamic-mysql-data-in-bootstrap-modal.html)
- Link to my live project: [Nalu.live/equipment](http://nalu.live/equipment.php#dataModal)
- Link to my [github repo](https://github.com/SDillon001/nalu_html) with all of the project code
  except for the DB connection
- Screenshot of [mySQl database](https://postimg.cc/image/6y12v4kmv/) I'm working with

**Main Project Files for this Issue:**

`equipment.php`,
`select.php`,
`surfboards.php`,
`surfboard.js`

**Notes:**

A working example is on [nalu.live.equipment](http://nalu.live/equipment.php#dataModal) in the "Surfboard Name" table on the page below the carousel. If you click on the 'View' button a modal opens with the corresponding name of the surfboard row and image that are loaded from the SQL database. The code to generate the modal is in `select.php`.

I'm trying to incorporate the same functionality from the table into the image grid below it so I can remove the example table. When the user clicks on a surfboard placeholder image the corresponding modal opens with info that matches the database ID for that image.

The image grid is being generated by JSON/JS in `surfboards.js`. The `surfboards.php` file is creating an associative array and echoing JSON. The JS in `surfboards.js` is looping through the data and appending a `div` to `#board_table` in `equipment.php`.

The modal link is on line 18 of `surfboard.js`. I can't sort out the syntax to trigger the `.view_data` function to include the info from the DB. I've added the `class="view_data"` to the `href` but that's obviously wrong.. I'm unsure how to open the modal *and* trigger the `click()`.

**Image Grid HTML**
- added `class=".view_data"` to bind click event:

```
      <div class="flexbox_container">
        <section class="view_data" id="board_table">
          <!-- surfboards.js will publish surfboards from database here -->
        </section>
      </div>
```

**Modal Code for Both Surfboard Table and Placeholder Images:**

```
<!-- Ajax Database Modal Start -->
      <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
        <div class="modal-dialog">  
          <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
              <h4 class="modal-title">Surfboard Details</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="surfboard_detail">  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
```

**JSON Parser - surfboard.js:**

```
//gets the JSON from our surfboards.php
$.getJSON("surfboards.php", function (data) {
  //loop through each surfboard in the JSON file and append a <div> with the surfboard information
  $.each(data.Surfboards, function (row) {
      $("#board_table").append(
        '<div class="photog-group clearfix"><figure class="cap-bot"><a href="equipment.php?id=' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.id 
        + '"><a href="#dataModal" class="view_data"><img class="photog-headshot" src="images/'
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="'
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName
        + '"></a><figcaption><p>Board Name: ' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.boardName 
        + '<br>Year Shaped: ' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.year + '</p></figcaption><figure></div>');
  });
});
```

**AJAX View Data Trigger:**

```
// Function that responds to 'View' button onclick on equipment.php and 
inserts information from database into modal id="dataModal" 
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.view_data').click(function(){  
     var surfboard_id = $(this).attr("id");  
     $.ajax({  
         url:"../select.php",  
         method:"post",  
         data:{surfboard_id:surfboard_id},  
         success:function(data){  
             $('#surfboard_detail').html(data);  
             $('#dataModal').modal("show");
             console.log(data);
         }  
     });  
  });  
});
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You need to debug your code, narrow down the issue and add all the relevant code into the question itself, not as a link off-site.

Comment: Sorry about that @magnuseriksson, I added the code itself above. As mentioned in my second line, the issue is I'm not triggering the `.view_data` function from the `href` on line 18 in `surfboard.js` so when a surfboard placeholder image is clicked nothing shows up in the modal.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the link, it helped with binding the click event, but I'm still unsure of how to pass the ID of a dynamically generated modal to the click event? I've updated my question.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Comment: @georgeawg apologies, I was trying to supply as much information as possible to so that whomever tried to answer would have everything they need. I will re-ask this question with less text and more succinct code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I solved this problem and posted the code in my updated question here [Pass Image ID - Array Index - to Modal from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045254/4043235) in case it's helpful to anyone else. If you reopen this question I will answer it here too..?